# c# display doc/docs in exactly format in website

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my code to read a doc/docs file.

it can read, but the output format not exactly as in the docs, if that any way to display exactly format in aspx?

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
    string strFilePath = @"C:\Users\Roy\Desktop\News.doc";

    object objFile = strFilePath;
    object objNull = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object objReadOnly = true;

    //Open Document
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc 
        = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref objFile, ref objNull,
                                 ref objReadOnly, ref objNull,
                                 ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull,
                                 ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull,
                                 ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull,
                                 ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull);

    int i = 1;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph objParagraph
             in Doc.Paragraphs)
    {
        try
        {
            Label1.Text += Doc.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        i++;
    } 

    wordApp.Quit(ref objNull, ref objNull, ref objNull);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you format your code a little bit? It looks awful.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, sorry, i am trying=)

Comment: and what is the exact question, If I understand you right the posted code works correctly.

Comment: @AndreasRohde, my output result is not exactly the same with the .doc, i wish to display exactly as what is inside .doc, right now the output not even space =(

Comment: I guess he wants to see his doc file on WWW exactly as he sees it in Word

Comment: @MadBoy , yes, you are right =)

Comment: @CheemunLow, you only took the `Range.Text` - member from the `Paragraph`, so why do you wonder, that there is no format and layout in your output. IF you want to format and layout the text you must also use other members like `Borders` or `Style`.

Comment: @AndreasRohde , can u provide some example for me?=)

Comment: @AndreasRohde, i think u got the point=)

Comment: @CheemunLow  you already excepted an answer.

Comment: @AndreasRohde, hi,i cant even find any example exactly that i want in internet and i've tried couple of hours already =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to use the WebBrowser control to open Office documents in Visual C# 2005 or in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=304662) may help you. There's another article here http://forums.asp.net/t/1068814.aspx/1 which opens up document in user's Word embedded in browser which may help if everything else fails. But I guess it requires user to have Office installed.